# Is there a way to remove the white space from underneath a boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I made a boxplot comparison using the code below and received the following output. Removing this white space would help with reducing the amount of pages taken up in a PDF knitted from a Rmd file, as I have about six of these plots. Note: That border isn't actually around the plots, I edited that in post to show where the extra white space is before and for my desired result.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2));
boxplot(will$movies.50$millions, main=will$name, ylim=c(0,360), ylab="Raw Millions");
boxplot(denzel$movies.50$millions, main=denzel$name, ylim=c(0,360), ylab="Raw Millions");
```

[With extra white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bWvS.png)

[Without extra white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuW3J.png)

Comment: Look into margin (`mar`) options in `?par`.

Comment: please provide the dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Thank you /users/1422451/parfait for the direction to point me in! I resolved it by editing the line

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2));
```

to

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(1,4,2,2));
```